# Viewing git logs without checking out

Tags: git, logging, github, repository

Is it possible to view the Git logs of a Git repo with a simple command; in other words, without downloading the repo?

I want to read the logs of several repositories on Github and parse them for certain statistics.

For example, for this:

https://github.com/shumsky/Player

I tried git log -p github.com/shumsky/Player but get an "ambiguous argument" message

I've never really used Git before.

Thanks

Comment: Odd, why would you be collecting statistics from git logs if you haven't really used git before?  Are you sure it's *logs* you want?  Why don't you describe the information you are actually trying to find from the logs, there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to find some candidate applications for a research study, and Github stores a huge number of potential apps.  I'm merely trying to sort through them based on certain criteria and narrow it down to a smaller few that I can look at it.

Comment: have you checked in any case whether *github* itself doesn't have a way to shw you these logs?

Comment: What sort of criteria?  How many changes? how many authors? what authors like to write about their changes? what day of the week they prefer to commit on?  nothing else can be found in the logs.

Comment: I would like to know info like how many changes, how many authors, how size of the project, ~# of lines of code

Comment: You can read the first two from the logs, but not the second two.  IIRC you can't read the logs without downloading.  Note that number of changes is ... mutable.  If people squash before commit or not you can get different numbers, also depends upon both developers and project policy.

Comment: Seems to me like using github itself to present tath data is a lot more efficient.  Take a look at this project I picked at random - you can view the files, branches authors and commits - what more do you want?

Comment: I guess it would be easier to do it that way.  The main thing is that I want to automate the process because there are at least several hundred that I want to search through...but I guess there's nothing stopping me from parsing the data from github.

Comment: Git is a distributed version control system (DVCS). All operations except synchronization commands are done locally. Therefore, you must download the whole repository (git clone).

Comment: You might find something helpful here http://developer.github.com/v3/

Answer (score 0):

As  [Pos5e5s3dFr3ak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156254/pos5e5s3dfr3ak) mentions in the comments, the way to automate queries against GitHub repos is to use [their API](http://developer.github.com/v3/):

The [Git commits API page](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/), for instance, can allow you to get the commits data (and their associated comments, part of the log) without having to clone the full repo.
But you can also query the `README` file, the forks (to see if there is activity on other clones for a particular projects), ...

Answer (score 0):

[Based on the Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/), here is the API call you should use

```
curl -u '<your-github-username>' https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-user>/<repo-project>/commits
```

For the [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) Library you could use:

```
curl -u '<your-github-username>' https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/commits > all-d3-commits.txt
```

Here is some output. Warning, its a lot of data.

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/commits/183060d40ffce8a8bd233feeedd80f84d4707642",
    "committer": {
      "type": "User",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/repos",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/subscriptions",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/gists{/gist_id}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/received_events",
      "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/005a27e09fe946ebef64bf4d134efc0a?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-user-420.png",
      "login": "mbostock",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/orgs",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/events{/privacy}",
      "gravatar_id": "005a27e09fe946ebef64bf4d134efc0a",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/followers",
      "id": 230541,
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/following"
    },
    "sha": "183060d40ffce8a8bd233feeedd80f84d4707642",
    "author": {
      "type": "User",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/repos",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/subscriptions",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/gists{/gist_id}",
     "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/received_events",
      "avatar_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/005a27e09fe946ebef64bf4d134efc0a?d=https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com%2Fimages%2Fgravatars%2Fgravatar-user-420.png",
      "login": "mbostock",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/orgs",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/events{/privacy}",
      "gravatar_id": "005a27e09fe946ebef64bf4d134efc0a",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/followers",
      "id": 230541,
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mbostock/following"
    },
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/commits/183060d40ffce8a8bd233feeedd80f84d4707642/comments",
    "parents": [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/commits/11a19ec03d21a2908ce2d0ceed954e6a41a58cfc",
        "sha": "11a19ec03d21a2908ce2d0ceed954e6a41a58cfc"
      }
    ],
    "commit": {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/git/commits/183060d40ffce8a8bd233feeedd80f84d4707642",
      "committer": {
        "email": "mbostock@gmail.com",
        "date": "2013-01-24T17:26:22Z",
        "name": "Mike Bostock"
```